# Usage of your and yours

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, possessives

When should one use `your` and `yours`. What is the difference in usage. Give some examples if possible, please. For example,

> **Your** question is interesting! Were those gloves his or **yours**?

Why do we use exactly **your** and **yours**

I found this article: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc. But it did not help me to figure out my problem. Since there is no explanation when to use **your** and when to use **yours**.

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question, so it's hard to answer specifically. Can you provide some specific examples, or specific sentences that you have questions about?

Comment: Have you read about the difference between [possessive pronouns and possessive determiners](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc)?  I feel like this question might get closed for not showing any evidence of research, because this is something that can be easily looked up.

Comment: _**Your** question is interesting! Were those gloves his or **yours**?_

Comment: @stangdon, if it is so easy to find out on the internet why don`t you answer it?

Comment: @ohidano - Because the point of StackExchange is to provide answers that *can't* be found in reference works.  If StackExchange were to simply answer questions for which you could find the answer in a reference work, then it would just duplicate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use possessive determiners before a noun. We use possessive pronouns in place of a noun.

> Possessive determiner: **your**.
>
> Possessive pronoun: **yours**.

We use **your** before noun. We use **yours** in place of a noun.

**Your** (noun)*question*(noun) is interesting! Were those gloves his or yours(we are talking about a male, male is a noun we use here yours instead of male`s)?

Comment: They are both genitive pronouns that function as determiners. The difference is that "your" is an 'dependent' genitive pronoun while "yours" is a 'dependent' genitive pronoun.